# If Order Has Status Processing

Tags: woocommerce

I need to check if there's any outstanding new orders with the status of processing. I wrote this code into my function but it doesn't work when there's no new orders for the processing status.

```
 if ( $order->has_status( 'processing' ) ) {
    
         echo "New Orders";
            
            } else {
            
            echo "No New Orders Today";
    
        }
```

I assume `has_status` isn't the correct function to use.

I need the output to print **No New Orders Today** when there's no orders with the status of processing.

The code does run perfectly when there's orders.

Also, i would like to print this on the Orders page for admins.

Comment: Couldn't you just use the 'Processing' status filter on the order overview page to see if there are any orders with the processing status?

Comment: You need to query your orders. $args = array( 'status' => array('wc-processing'),); $orders = wc_get_orders( $args ); . After that do w/e you want with $orders :) At this page you can find useful examples how to use wc_get_orders() https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/wc_get_orders-and-WC_Order_Query

Comment: Error: Call to a member function get_id()